# How do we change the equation $x^{2} + y^{2} + xy - x - y = 0$ to the standard form of ellipse?

Tags: geometry

How do we change the equation $x^{2} + y^{2} + xy - x - y  = 0$ to the standard form of ellipse?

Since there have a term $xy$ , I don't know how to use completing square method.

Comment: What do you mean by standard form? If you're asking to write it as $\frac{(x-x_0)^2}{a^2} + \frac{(y-y_0)^2}{b^2} = 1$ you will run into problems. Just plot it with a computer to see why.

Comment: If by standard form you mean $\frac {(x-h)^2}{a^2} + \frac {(y - k)^2}{b^2} = 1$, then it's impossible. You could do it if you change coordinates though, but it would no longer be an equation with $x, y$, but rather one with some other variables, like $u, v$.

Comment: This kind of terms $xy$ appears when the axis of the ellipse are no longer parallel to $Ox$ and $Oy$.

Comment: Try the transformation $u = x + y$ and $v = x - y$.

Comment: $(3x+3y-2)^2 + 3(x-y)^2 = 4$

Answer (score 1):

As you can see this equation corresponds to an ellipse rotated an angle $\theta$.
[image]

Let $Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2+Dx+Ex+F=0$ then $\cot2\theta=\frac{A-C}{B}=0$, then $\theta=\frac{\pi}{4}$. So we do
\begin{align}
x&=x'cos\theta-y'\sin\theta=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}(x'-y')\\
y&=x'sin\theta+y'\cos\theta=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}(x'+y')
\end{align}

Then $\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}(x'-y')\right)^2+\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}(x'+y')\right)^2+\frac{1}{2}((x')^2-(y')^2)-\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}(x'-y')-\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}(x'+y')=0$
computing we have:

$$
\frac{\left(x'-\frac{\sqrt 2}{3}\right)^2}{\left(\frac{\sqrt 2}{3}\right)^2}+\frac{(y')^2}{\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}^2}=1.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Is this you are looking for?

\begin{align*}
x^{2} + y^{2} + xy - x - y = 0 & \Longleftrightarrow 2x^{2} + 2y^{2} 
+ 2xy - 2x - 2y = 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (x^{2} + 2xy + y^{2}) + (x^{2} - 2x + 1) + (y^{2} - 2y + 1) = 2\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (x + y)^{2} + (x - 1)^{2} + (y - 1)^{2} = 2
\end{align*}